# SCCM2012 SP2 Scripted Deployment fails, running script manually succeeds though

Tags: powershell, installshield, sccm

I am installing a program through SCCM2012 SP2 with a PowerShell Script and it fails with an install shield ResponseCode -3, running the Powershell script manually from C:\windows\ccmcache#\ succeeds though...

This is my command line (it works for dozens of other scripts - including installshield packaged scripts)...

```
"%WINDIR%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file .\InstallTigerpaw.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the system error code 3, it means '**File Not Found**'.  Running manually from cache is different with executing by CM agent. Below is something I will take into consideration when try to deploy a PowerShell Script using Program.

**First**,
To deploy a script using Configuration Manager, I always test it first by running it manually under **System Context**, which is the same context that CM deployments run under. I use [PSExec tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) to open a new command prompt under system context by running `psexec /s cmd.exe` in a common command prompt.

**Second**,
The command you use in the program. In your case, use **Sysnative** only when you intend to access system32 folder on a 64 bit operating system. If not, then don't need it.

**Third**,
The **Execution Policy**. Microsoft allows you to temporarily bypass the execution policy to get work done, that's a reason that I usually use **Bypass**. Example like:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\PowerShellScriptFileName.ps1"
```

Most of the time the deployment goes fine on clients. In case of problems, I will look at client side log, **execmgr.log**.

In some cases, we may need to set '**Only when a user is logged on**', '**Run with administrative rights**' for specific needs of running scripts.